# What is the use of Celery in python?

Tags: python, celery

I am confused in celery.Example i want to load a data file and it takes 10 seconds to load without celery.With celery how will the user be benefited? Will it take same time to load data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery, and similar systems like Huey are made to help us distribute (offload) the amount of processes that normally can't execute *concurrently* on a single machine, or it would lead to significant performance degradation if you do so. The key word here is DISTRIBUTED.

You mentioned downloading of a file. If it is a single file you need to download, and that is all, then you do not need Celery. How about more complex scenario - you need to download 100000 files? How about even more complex - these 100000 files need to be parsed and the parsing process is CPU intensive?

Moreover, Celery will help you with retrying of failed tasks, logging, monitoring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the user has to wait to load the data file to be done on the server. But with the help of celery, the operation will be performed on the server and the user will not be involved. Even if the app crashes, that task will be queued.

> Celery will keep track of the work you send to it in a database
>   back-end such as Redis or RabbitMQ. This keeps the state out of your
>   app server's process which means even if your app server crashes your
>   job queue will still remain. Celery also allows you to track tasks
>   that fail.

Comment: Ok I try to complete that